# opencv circle detection with video

Tags: c, opencv, detection, video-processing, geometry

is there a way to wait until something happens(while loop) or wait wait 10 seconds before doing a circle detection, but still displaying the video. i have tried it with while loop but if condition is not met, frames will not be displayed as code does not get the cvShow\iamge().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **it's possible**, but you will have to use threads. Declare a global variable `bool exec_circle_detection = false;` and start a 2nd thread. On this thread, call `sleep(10)` to wait for 10 seconds and then change `exec_circle_detection` to **true**.

In the main thread, inside the frame grabbing loop, you check if the boolean variable is set to true, and in case it isn't, you won't process the frame. This part would look something like this (in C):

```
char key = 0;
while (key != 27) // ESC
{    
  frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
  if (!frame) 
  {
      fprintf( stderr, "!!! cvQueryFrame failed!\n" );
      break;
  }

  if (exec_circle_detection)
  {
      // execute custom processing
  }

  // Display processed frame
  cvShowImage("result", frame);

  // Exit when user press ESC
  key = cvWaitKey(10);
}
```

If you plan to do the circle detection once every 10 seconds, you will need to change `exec_circle_detection` to false after you execute the custom processing. On the secondary thread, adjust your code so there is a `while` loop changing `exec_circle_detection` to true every 10 seconds.

Comment: thanks a  lot. i plan to do a circle detection, then want the programme to do nothing except show the video for the next ten seconds. then return to the next line of code.

Comment: Awesome, feel free to upvote my answer or to select it as the official answer to your question by clicking in the checkbox near it. Or do both :)

Comment: complicated question maybe. i have a part in my code which is detecting for circles. i want it to count 10 seconds and detect circles and display video without running into next lines of code???

Comment: Well, I already suggested an approach to deal with that. The main thread of your application is going to stay retrieving frames from the camera, and it will only execute your custom processing when the `exec_circle_detection` turns true. This part will be accomplished by a 2nd thread that will run and call `sleep(10)`, which *pauses* code execution on this thread for 10 seconds, and when this time is up the next instruction to be executed should be `exec_circle_detection = true;`, which will trigger your circle detection code to be executed in the main thread. Does this makes sense to you?

Comment: i understand most if.are the 2 threads in the main(). i want code the following. if(xpos!=oldx){ printf("white ball moving") }. then if this is executed i would like the 10sec "do nothing" to execute.

Comment: Great, let us know if you have any more problems. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the detection every `X` frames. Add a frame counter in your code, restarting to 0 when detection is perform, increase by one at each grabbed new frame, and perform detection when the counter is equal to `300` considering your video is displayed at `30 fps`. You will get your 10 seconds delay between each detections.

Comment: What if the application is supposed to work with different types of cameras and not just one? A more reliable solution is to use a timing mechanism, as described in my answer.